# How to create a Custom date-picker in android compatible till jellybeans

Tags: android, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

I'm working with date picker in android. I checked many github projects and questions but can not find a view like that as in  picture. I used many codes but in vain. Now I am using this code

```html
public void showDatePicker() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getLayoutInflater( bundle);
        final AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder =
                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.current_project_fragment, null);
        dialogBuilder.setView(customView);
        final    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        final DatePicker datePicker =
                (DatePicker) customView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_datepicker);
        final TextView dateTextView =
                (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_dateview);
        final SimpleDateFormat dateViewFormatter =
                new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd",Locale.ENGLISH);
        final SimpleDateFormat formatter =
                new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd",Locale.ENGLISH);
        // Minimum date
        Calendar minDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        try {
            minDate.setTime(formatter.parse("12.12.2010"));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        datePicker.setMinDate(minDate.getTimeInMillis());
        // View settings
        dialogBuilder.setTitle("Choose a date");
        Calendar choosenDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = choosenDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = choosenDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = choosenDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        try {
            Date choosenDateFromUI = formatter.parse(
                    dateTextView.getText().toString()
            );
            choosenDate.setTime(choosenDateFromUI);
            year = choosenDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            month = choosenDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            day = choosenDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Calendar dateToDisplay = Calendar.getInstance();
        dateToDisplay.set(year, month, day);
        dateTextView.setText(
                dateViewFormatter.format(dateToDisplay.getTime())
        );
        // Buttons
        dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(
                "Go to today",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dateTextView.setText(
                                formatter.format(now.getTime())
                        );
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
        );
        dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(
                "Choose",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Calendar choosen = Calendar.getInstance();
                        choosen.set(
                                datePicker.getYear(),
                                datePicker.getMonth(),
                                datePicker.getDayOfMonth()
                        );
                        dateTextView.setText(
                                dateViewFormatter.format(choosen.getTime())
                        );
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
        );
        final AlertDialog dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
        // Initialize datepicker in dialog atepicker
        datePicker.init(
                year,
                month,
                day,
                new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
                    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year,
                                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        Calendar choosenDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                        choosenDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                        dateTextView.setText(
                                dateViewFormatter.format(choosenDate.getTime())
                        );
                        if (choosenDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) ==
                                Calendar.SUNDAY ||
                                now.compareTo(choosenDate) < 0) {
                            dateTextView.setTextColor(
                                    Color.parseColor("#ff0000")
                            );
                            ((Button) dialog.getButton(
                                    AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE))
                                    .setEnabled(false);
                        } else {
                            dateTextView.setTextColor(
                                    Color.parseColor("#000000")
                            );
                            ((Button) dialog.getButton(
                                    AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE))
                                    .setEnabled(true);
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
        // Finish
        dialog.show();
    }
```

Please help me to create view like this . [image: this]